# Resharper intellisense won't work for XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper

The Resharper intellisense does not seem to work for me in XAML
My Xaml looks like

```
<Window x:Class="GraphicalLuaEditor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GraphicalLuaEditor"
    xmlns:nodeScriptingEditor="clr-namespace:NodeScriptingEditor;assembly=NodeScriptingEditor"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow">
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

and my xaml.cs looks like

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace GraphicalLuaEditor
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
          DataContext = this;
          InitializeComponent();
       }

       public string Test { get; set; } = "ÖÖÖH";

       private void CommonCommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }
}
```

When I edit the XAML I expect it to help me with the data binding by suggesting properties from the code behind but it doesn't. At work where I seemingly do nothing different it works!
Also, it complains about it Can't resolve symbol Test due to unknown data context

Comment: I have never found Resharper to work well with XAML. I had similar issues and could not find a definitive solution. granted i didnt look hard. I found if i built the project it would sometimes (at random) cause resharper to work better.

Comment: You won't get any intellisense if you use code-behind to set the `DataContext`. If it doesn't see it in XAML, then it won't know what you want. All of this can be remedied by using MVVM. You will get intellisense from both the designer and Resharper.

Comment: @Laith How do I set up MVVM? do you have any links to useful resources or an example

Comment: Google MVVM + WPF, I'm sure there are hundreds of tutorials. And have a look at what @ASh wrote below. Using `d:DataContext` is my recommendation as it leaves you in charge of setting the `DataContext` programmatically later, but tells the designer what you intend to bind.

Answer (score 3):

Intellisense does not work for xaml binding expressions unless DataContext is set in xaml too.

if Window iteslf is used as a DataContext, the following binding can be used:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...>
```

if there is a specialized view model, design-time DataContext can be used:

```
<Window d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MyViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" ...>
```