# Is binding to a ViewModel property instead of using DataContext a valid way to connect a ViewModel to view?

Tags: .net, wpf

Most of the stuff I read about MVVM in WPF talks about connecting the view to the view model by somehow setting the DataContext of the view to an instance of the view model. I don't like using DataContext as it's not typed, and therefore intellisense doesn't work.

I am thinking of using an approach where the view has a property called ViewModel which is set to an instance of the property. Since this property has specific type, I can bind to a property of the view model like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ViewModel.Property1, ElementName=_viewWindow}"/>
```

where _viewWindow is the name applied to view class (which could be a Window or UserControl for example). Whilst this is a bit more verbose than binding via DataContext it has the advantage that intellisense will work.

The view model will implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Is this a valid approach? I haven't seen any references to the approach in anything I have read about MVVM but it seems like a reasonable idea.

Are there other advantages to using DataContext that I am missing apart from shorter binding syntax?

One thing I did see in another answer was adding a property that casts DataContext to the view model type.

Comment: And where will you derive from `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: The ViewModel will implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I think data binding updates should work fine with this approach.

Comment: DataContext set for top-level element is inherited by all child elements. it really shorten binding paths. if you want Intellisense support, take a look at [d:DataContext / d:DesignInstance example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48966829/1506454), [d:DataContext / d:DesignInstance example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46726407/1506454)

Comment: @ASh - this is an interesting idea, I did some experiments with it. Intelisense will show the properties of my view model but will show many other properties as well. Also it won''t flag an error if I type a property that doesn't exist on my view model. Also it requires that my view model has a default constructor. With the method I have described above the checking seems to be more strict.So it seems the main advantage of `DataContext` is short path syntax anywhere down the control tree of my view?

Comment: " Also it requires that my view model has a default constructor" - not really, set `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False` if there is no default ctor. "it won't flag an error if I type a property that doesn't exist on my view model" - it does for me. even in VS 2010.

Comment: _Also it won''t flag an error if I type a property that doesn't exist on my view model_ This can be helpful for you:[Detect in XAML broken bindings already at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208011/detect-in-xaml-broken-bindings-already-at-compile-time)

Answer (score 2):

If you set your data context via XAML your intellisense will work.

```
<Window 
...>
<Window.DataContext>
    <MyViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

If you don't like coupling your view to a specific implementation, you can actually use an interface for the view model:

```
<Window
...>
<Window.DataContext>
    <x:Type Type="IMyViewModel" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

You would then need to set the DataContext via the code behind.

```
public class MyView
{
    public MyView(IMyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
        this.DataContext = myViewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful but the intelisense doesn't work as well (see my comment above on setting a design instance) as binding to specific property. I didn't realize that setting DataContext to a type object worked int this way - is this documented by MS somewhere?

Comment: @Shane hmm, strangely I've never had any difficulties with intellisense. Sometimes once the data context is changed a rebuild may be required to help move things along. Also setting the data context via XAML is not restricted to the window, it can be set on pretty much any framework element (i.e. Grid, ListBox etc..) [here is some more info I found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have seen the data context set in xaml before but what is new to me is setting it to the type of the view model instead of an instance of the view model as you have done above. It seems in the case you telling VS at design time what type the DataContext will be set to at run time.

Comment: Ah apologies, yes it is not very well known, I only stumbled upon it myself not long ago. It essentially has the same effect on intellisense as IsDesignTimeCreatable=false, and I imagine something similar is happening under the hood. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation about it on MSDN.

Comment: I like this solution but intelisense is not quite working right for me. What version of Visual Studio are you using? I tried it on 2 computers and the behavior is the same. If I type `{Binding Path=` and press Ctrl-Space I see the properties of the view model but it doesn't show squiggly lines if I type something which is not a valid property. I am using VS 2017.

Comment: In both VS2013 and 2017 If I type `{Binding Path=` followed by a property that is not present in the view model I get a XAML 'squiggly line' error, stating `Cannot resolve property 'invalid' in data context of type 'MyViewModel'`. It is not shown as an error or warning in the error list window though, so perhaps its my ReSharper that is providing the error? Do you have ReSharper?

Comment: No, don't have ReSharper.

Comment: Ah - I have looked into my R# settings and indeed, showing warnings for unresolved binding paths is a [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) feature. If you have not come across it before, I would suggest doing so. I consider it essential. If a license is not affordable, [they have discounted/free editions](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/#edition=discounts) for personal use/open source/education so if you fall into any of those categories seriously consider getting it as I can't recommend it highly enough.